# Bearer token expiration in Java

Tags: java, rest, web-services, access-token, bearer-token

I am calling below `API` to get bearer `access token`.

```
POST https://idcs-xxxx.identity.c9dev2.oc9qadev.com/oauth2/v1/token
```

Once the `token` is retrieved i will use the same `token` in below `APIs`. These `APIs` are part of single `transaction`. But every time I call these `APIs`,I have to pass the `token` for `authorization`. I dont want to generate `token` again and again because It is valid for 60 min. ***How can I check whether token is expired or not.*** .If it is expired then only I want to generate again, else i want to use the existing one. I am not using any framework to call the APIs in java.I am using `HttpUrlConnection`.

```
GET https://idcs-xxxx.identity-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/skills

GET https://idcs-xxxx-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/skills/dynamicEntities

POST https://idcs-xxxx.identity-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/bots/xxx/v2/yyy

PATCH https://idcs-xxxx.identity-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/bots/xxx

PUT https://idcs-xxxx.identity-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/bots/xxx/DONE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible concept: Write a Helper class to do the API request (e.g. MyAPIClient.class). Most APIs will return a 401 HTTP error when the token is expired. Check this behaviour for this specific api. If this is the case, get a new token within this helper class and repeat the request with the new token. Cache this token for 60min after you got it (different Java Frameworks have different kind of Cache providers you can use for this). Use the helper class everywhere you want to access the api